# Assigning ID to consecutive integers

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I need to assign an ID to groups of consecutive integers. The ID will be used later to identify MIN / MAX values and for some other grouping. I *think* this is a gaps / islands issue I just can't quite get my head around it.

This is the data I have to work with:

| tenant_id | tenancy_type | a_other | b_other | lease_date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 356778 | R | Z | Q | 01/01/2012 |
| 356778 | R | Z | Q | 01/02/2012 |
| 356778 | R | Z | Q | 01/03/2012 |
| 356778 | R | Z | Q | 01/04/2012 |
| 356778 | R | Z | Q | 01/05/2012 |
| 356778 | C | B | E | 01/07/2015 |
| 356778 | C | B | E | 01/08/2015 |
| 356778 | C | B | E | 01/09/2015 |
| 356778 | C | B | E | 01/10/2015 |
| 356778 | C | B | E | 01/11/2015 |
| 356778 | R | Z | Q | 01/01/2019 |
| 356778 | R | Z | Q | 01/02/2019 |
| 356778 | R | Z | Q | 01/03/2019 |
| 356778 | R | Z | Q | 01/04/2019 |
| 356778 | R | Z | Q | 01/05/2019 |
| 356778 | R | Z | Q | 01/06/2019 |
| 356778 | R | Z | Q | 01/07/2019 |
| 356778 | R | Z | Q | 01/08/2019 |
| 356778 | R | Z | Q | 01/09/2019 |
| 356778 | R | Z | Q | 01/10/2019 |
| 356778 | R | Z | Q | 01/11/2019 |
| 356778 | R | Z | Q | 01/12/2019 |
| 356778 | R | Z | E | 01/01/2020 |

So far I've managed to populate an additional column with consecutive integers that reset back to 1 where appropriate:

| tenant_id | tenancy_type | a_other | b_other | lease_date | lease_month_no |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 356778 | R | Z | Q | 01/01/2012 | 1 |
| 356778 | R | Z | Q | 01/02/2012 | 2 |
| 356778 | R | Z | Q | 01/03/2012 | 3 |
| 356778 | R | Z | Q | 01/04/2012 | 4 |
| 356778 | R | Z | Q | 01/05/2012 | 5 |
| 356778 | C | B | E | 01/07/2015 | 1 |
| 356778 | C | B | E | 01/08/2015 | 2 |
| 356778 | C | B | E | 01/09/2015 | 3 |
| 356778 | C | B | E | 01/10/2015 | 4 |
| 356778 | C | B | E | 01/11/2015 | 5 |
| 356778 | R | Z | Q | 01/01/2019 | 1 |
| 356778 | R | Z | Q | 01/02/2019 | 2 |
| 356778 | R | Z | Q | 01/03/2019 | 3 |
| 356778 | R | Z | Q | 01/04/2019 | 4 |
| 356778 | R | Z | Q | 01/05/2019 | 5 |
| 356778 | R | Z | Q | 01/06/2019 | 6 |
| 356778 | R | Z | Q | 01/07/2019 | 7 |
| 356778 | R | Z | Q | 01/08/2019 | 8 |
| 356778 | R | Z | Q | 01/09/2019 | 9 |
| 356778 | R | Z | Q | 01/10/2019 | 10 |
| 356778 | R | Z | Q | 01/11/2019 | 11 |
| 356778 | R | Z | Q | 01/12/2019 | 12 |
| 356778 | R | Z | E | 01/01/2020 | 13 |

I've used the code below to achieve this:

```
SELECT     
    tenant_id,
    tenancy_type,
    a_other,
    b_other,
    lease_date,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY tenant_id, tenancy_type, RN1-RN2 ORDER BY lease_date) AS lease_month_no
FROM 
    (
        SELECT 
            tenant_id,
            tenancy_type,
            a_other,
            b_other,
            lease_date,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY tenant_id ORDER BY lease_date) AS RN1,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY tenant_id, tenancy_type ORDER BY lease_date) AS RN2
        FROM dbo.lease_info
    ) 
AS x
ORDER BY lease_date
```

The trouble I'm having is then assigning a grouping ID to the integer groups so I have an output like this:

| tenant_id | tenancy_type | a_other | b_other | lease_date | lease_month_no | group_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 356778 | R | Z | Q | 01/01/2012 | 1 | 1 |
| 356778 | R | Z | Q | 01/02/2012 | 2 | 1 |
| 356778 | R | Z | Q | 01/03/2012 | 3 | 1 |
| 356778 | R | Z | Q | 01/04/2012 | 4 | 1 |
| 356778 | R | Z | Q | 01/05/2012 | 5 | 1 |
| 356778 | C | B | E | 01/07/2015 | 1 | 2 |
| 356778 | C | B | E | 01/08/2015 | 2 | 2 |
| 356778 | C | B | E | 01/09/2015 | 3 | 2 |
| 356778 | C | B | E | 01/10/2015 | 4 | 2 |
| 356778 | C | B | E | 01/11/2015 | 5 | 2 |
| 356778 | R | Z | Q | 01/01/2019 | 1 | 3 |
| 356778 | R | Z | Q | 01/02/2019 | 2 | 3 |
| 356778 | R | Z | Q | 01/03/2019 | 3 | 3 |
| 356778 | R | Z | Q | 01/04/2019 | 4 | 3 |
| 356778 | R | Z | Q | 01/05/2019 | 5 | 3 |
| 356778 | R | Z | Q | 01/06/2019 | 6 | 3 |
| 356778 | R | Z | Q | 01/07/2019 | 7 | 3 |
| 356778 | R | Z | Q | 01/08/2019 | 8 | 3 |
| 356778 | R | Z | Q | 01/09/2019 | 9 | 3 |
| 356778 | R | Z | Q | 01/10/2019 | 10 | 3 |
| 356778 | R | Z | Q | 01/11/2019 | 11 | 3 |
| 356778 | R | Z | Q | 01/12/2019 | 12 | 3 |
| 356778 | R | Z | E | 01/01/2020 | 13 | 3 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maybe ?

```
    CREATE TABLE #leaseinfo(
   tenant_id      INTEGER  NOT NULL
  ,tenancy_type   VARCHAR(1) NOT NULL
  ,a_other        VARCHAR(1) NOT NULL
  ,b_other        VARCHAR(1) NOT NULL
  ,lease_date     DATE  NOT NULL
);
INSERT INTO #leaseinfo(tenant_id,tenancy_type,a_other,b_other,lease_date) VALUES
 (356778,'R','Z','Q','2012-01-01')
,(356778,'R','Z','Q','2012-01-02')
,(356778,'R','Z','Q','2012-01-03')
,(356778,'R','Z','Q','2012-01-04')
,(356778,'R','Z','Q','2012-01-05')
,(356778,'C','B','E','2015-01-07')
,(356778,'C','B','E','2015-01-08')
,(356778,'C','B','E','2015-01-09')
,(356778,'C','B','E','2015-01-10')
,(356778,'C','B','E','2015-01-11')
,(356778,'R','Z','Q','2019-01-01')
,(356778,'R','Z','Q','2019-01-02')
,(356778,'R','Z','Q','2019-01-03')
,(356778,'R','Z','Q','2019-01-04')
,(356778,'R','Z','Q','2019-01-05')
,(356778,'R','Z','Q','2019-01-06')
,(356778,'R','Z','Q','2019-01-07')
,(356778,'R','Z','Q','2019-01-08')
,(356778,'R','Z','Q','2019-01-09')
,(356778,'R','Z','Q','2019-01-10')
,(356778,'R','Z','Q','2019-01-11')
,(356778,'R','Z','Q','2019-01-12')
,(356778,'R','Z','E','2020-01-01')
,(435677,'R','Z','Q','2012-01-01')
,(435677,'R','Z','Q','2012-01-02')
,(435677,'R','Z','Q','2012-01-03')
,(435677,'R','Z','Q','2012-01-04')
,(435677,'R','Z','Q','2012-01-05')
,(435677,'C','B','E','2015-01-07')
,(435677,'C','B','E','2015-01-08')
,(435677,'C','B','E','2015-01-09')
,(435677,'C','B','E','2015-01-10')
,(435677,'C','B','E','2015-01-11')
,(435677,'R','Z','Q','2019-01-01')
,(435677,'R','Z','Q','2019-01-02');

    ;WITH Grp AS
    (
      SELECT 
          tenant_id,
          tenancy_type,
          a_other,
          b_other,
          lease_date,
          ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY tenant_id ORDER BY lease_date) AS RN1,
          ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY tenant_id, tenancy_type ORDER BY lease_date) AS RN2,
        CASE
          WHEN tenancy_type = LAG(tenancy_type,1,tenancy_type) OVER
            ( PARTITION BY tenant_id ORDER BY lease_date ASC) THEN 0
         ELSE 1
         END AS GRPNo
       FROM #leaseinfo
        ) 
    
    SELECT     
        tenant_id,
        tenancy_type,
        a_other,
        b_other,
        lease_date,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY tenant_id, tenancy_type, RN1-RN2 ORDER BY lease_date) AS lease_month_no,
        SUM(GRPNo) OVER  ( PARTITION BY tenant_id  ORDER BY  lease_date ASC
        ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND  CURRENT ROW) + 1 AS GRP_NO
    FROM  GRP
```

Comment: see https://www.sqlservercentral.com/forums/topic/islands-and-gaps-im-stuck-again for idea for this solution....read the thread for detail on POC index as well

Answer (score 2):

`DENSE_RANK()` Window function will help you to achieve this.

```
SELECT     
    tenant_id,
    tenancy_type,
    a_other,
    b_other,
    lease_date,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY tenant_id, tenancy_type, RN1-RN2 ORDER BY lease_date) AS lease_month_no
    DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY tenant_id, tenancy_type ORDER BY lease_date) AS Group_Id
FROM 
    (
        SELECT 
            tenant_id,
            tenancy_type,
            a_other,
            b_other,
            lease_date,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY tenant_id ORDER BY lease_date) AS RN1,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY tenant_id, tenancy_type ORDER BY lease_date) AS RN2
        FROM dbo.lease_info
    ) 
AS x
ORDER BY lease_date
```

Comment: Thank you but DENSE_RANK here is outputting a unique ID per row whereas I need a unique row per group of 'lease_month_no' as in the 3rd table. Unless I've misunderstood your answer, which is possible!